# MVC Displaying Database Queries on View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application with many data grids backed by an oracle database. I would like to be able to display the query that is backing each specific grid on the page in some way. The queries are dynamic depending on what parameters are passed to them so I would like to be able to display the final query that goes to the database. I am not sure how I can achieve this without having to write a separate function for every query to be able to return the end result. My only idea is to do something like this:

```
public class DatabaseResult<T> 
{
    public QueryInformation queryInfo { get; set; }
    public List<T> data { get; set; }
}
public class QueryInformation {
    //various properties about the query
    public string query { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my data provider I will do this:

```
    public DatabaseResult<RestProgressGridModel> getGridData(string orgkey, string lvlnumdd, string lvlnum)
    {
        List<RestProgressGridModel> data = new List<RestProgressGridModel>();
        string grid = query.Replace("{orgkey}", orgkey).Replace("{lvlnum}", lvlnum).Replace("{lvlnumdd}", lvlnumdd);
        foreach (DataRow dr in FillDataTableFromQuery(grid).Rows)
        {
            data.Add(new RestProgressGridModel { });
        }
        return new DatabaseResult<RestProgressGridModel> {
            data = data,
            test = new QueryInformation {query = query }
        };
    }
```

From here I'm not sure how I will be able to access this on the view itself. I could store the query into the ViewBag but I am not sure if that is the best approach.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess by you asking how to display the queries generated, you're using some kind of ORM (such as EF)?

Comment: I have the query itself, I actually write it as a string. The thing I need is to then take that query I wrote and display it on the page itself (with the parameters passed to the query like so `query.Replace("{orgkey}", orgkey);`).

Comment: Sorry, I'd probably not read the question properly. So is it just displaying the query on the View, you're asking for help with?. You could use the ViewBag, as you suggested. Nothing wrong with that. Alternatively, you could write a ViewModel which takes your data and the query, so you can display it on the View.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but aren't you already passing the `query` to the View?:

> ```
> return new DatabaseResult<RestProgressGridModel> {
>      data = data,
>      test = new QueryInformation {query = query } // shouldn't this be query = new...?
>  };
> ```

---

Where you're creating a `DatabaseResult<RestProgressGridModel>`, you're setting the `test` (which I think should be `queryInfo`) property, which contains the query itself.

Can't you just use this in the View directly?

```
<p>@Model.queryInfo.query</p>
```

---

*A couple of other helpful pointers:*

In C#, Properties are conventionally named in `PascalCase` with a Capital letter at the start.

Try to avoid using `camelCase`, as this conventionally is used for local variables (or private fields, ideally prefixed with an `_`).

It helps readability for you, and for anyone reading your code.